# Ignore Non Serialized property in BinaryFormatter Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, serialization

I have a class called `User`and it is `[Serializable]` and inherited from base class `IdentityUser` an Entity Framework class and Non Serializable.

I have a property in `Booking` class with type `User` and `Booking` class is `Serializable` I am trying to serialize the booking object using `BinaryFormatter`  but I can't because of `IdentityUser` class and I get this error :

> 'Type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser' in
>   Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as
>   serializable.'

Is there a way to ignore this property because I don't think there is away to make 'IdentityUser' as Serializable.

```
[Serializable]
public class User : IdentityUser
{
   public String FirstName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Booking
{
   [ForeignKey("Guest")]
   public string GuestId { set; get; }
   public virtual User Guest { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`BinaryFormatter` serializes the [public and private fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx) of a object -- not the properties.  For an [auto-implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) the secret backing field is what is actually serialized.

Normally, if you do not want a field to be serialized, you can apply the [`[NonSerialized]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nonserializedattribute) attribute, and `BinaryFormatter` will skip it.  In c# 7.3 and later, it's possible to do this to the secret backing field of an auto-implemented property by using a field-targeted attribute:

```
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public virtual User Guest { set; get; }
```

See: [Auto-Implemented Property Field-Targeted Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/auto-prop-field-attrs) and [What's new in C# 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3).

Prior to c# 7.3 there is no way to apply an attribute to the backing field of an auto-implemented property.  Thus you need to make the backing field be explicit:

```
[Serializable]
public class Booking
{
    [ForeignKey("Guest")]
    public string GuestId { set; get; }

    [NonSerialized]
    User guest;

    public virtual User Guest { set { guest = value; } get { return guest; } }
}
```

Incidentally, if you *need* to serialize some of the information in `User`, you could consider implementing [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or replacing instances of `User` with [serialization surrogates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).